# What volcanic gases & factors, isolated in pockets/caves under an oceanic crust, could create odd ecosystems and new extremophiles?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, oxygen

A crack is found near the Mariana Trench that forms a long tunnel with pockets to trap bubbles/gases from deep in the lithosphere...what elements could get trapped and possibly form a new ecosystem for new extremophiles?

Comment: Need some context here. Since Obama, etc, never did go to Antarctica, and since you give us no setup about why they went, any answer to your question is equally plausible answer from "alien space craft" to "to get to the other side."

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Try skeptics.SE...

Comment: WHAT??? I'm totally in confusion. I vote to close this question, if I'm able to.

Comment: This is a site to ask questions. There are plenty of places to share creative work, but if you are not asking anything of us this is the wrong place.

Comment: Is this a scenario, or are you asking a question?

Comment: So, you edited out your questions and replaced them with delusional statements. Have you considered a career in politics?

Comment: The facts are there...if you look.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site and how it works...I've been reading more about what to do and say.

Answer (score 6):

Taking your questions one at a time:

> Did the Patriarch of the Russian Orthodox church return an artifact to
>   some advanced race living under the ice?

No.

> Did Obama and other leaders try to meet them,

No.

> and if so, what is truly going on down there.

Nothing, unless you count mating penguins and blizzards.

EDIT - Oh, and I forgot about the enormous crack in one of the ice shelves. It looks as if we're about to get the world's largest iceburg. Now, that's interesting. END EDIT

> Operation High Jump in 1947 was rumored to be attacked by UFO's with
>   Nazi insignias,

UFOs attacked the ships and did no damage? Good news for us, bad news for the aliens. You'd think that aliens would be able to do some damage, wouldn't you? Pretty wimpy aliens, if you ask me.

> and other information on Antarctica suggests there are underground
>   pyramids, ancient technology, and even a hidden "hollow Earth" portal
>   exists there.

Really? Fascinating.

> Admiral Byrd the great explorer said many strange things after his
>   last visit, and mentioned craft that could travel from pole to pole in
>   an instant, plus other strange comments. Why is this so classified and
>   not open for everyone to explore.

Actually, he didn't. He did refer to the possibility of aerial attacks across the poles, but he seems to have been speaking in general terms. If these comments are classified (and they are not), how do you know about them?

> What is being hidden?

Nothing.

> Are the world-wide grid of pyramids part of an ancient power source?

Since there is no such grid, the answer is no.